# App works on debug stepping but not on normal debug or run mode

Tags: javascript, java, android

I have had some problems with one of my codes lately and now that I managed to get it working it crashes every time I run it. The problem is that when I debug step by step the app works but when I take off the steps it crashes every time...

This is the code:

```
String r = users.getListRatings();

    userHolder.tx_listratings.setText("     /     " + getAverage(r) + "     \uD83C\uDF1F"); //crashes here: at com.example.juanpablo.coffee.UserListAdapter.getView(UserListAdapter.java:86)


public int getAverage(String args) {
    String a = args;
    String[] x = a.split("");
    int add = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
        add = add + Integer.parseInt(x[i]); }
    int average = add / a.length(); //crashes here: at com.example.juanpablo.coffee.UserListAdapter.getAverage(UserListAdapter.java:114)
    return average;
}
```

This is the crash: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero.

Please help me if you can and if downvote please explain why, I am new and need to improve. Thank you.

Comment: It's because `a` is an empty string at that point.. The easiest fix would be to add an empty string check before that statement

Comment: but why does it work on stepping then?

Comment: what has it to do with javascript?

Comment: oops, sorry....

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the a.length() to i.